# Progress bar with multiple actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, progress-bar

I have designed a progress bar that I'd like to use when I load a grid (I load a datagridview from a stored procedure).  However the process that calls the stored procedure has a few different items it calls (see below).  I'm early on in getting the progress bar to work (it doesn't in the code below, hence why Im here), but my question is this.

Can the progress bar properly wok when the progress of what I'm tracking is multiple different methods.  The "LoadGrid" method is the one I'd really like to track progress of, as that is the processing of the stored procedure and loading of datagridview (i.e. the time consuimng processes).  I guess I'm more asking what's the proper technique as opposed to the exact code to use, but I'm limited in knowedge on progress bars.  I know I could use a just a random icon that says "busy" but I'd rather have the progress bar if its possible to do legitimately.

```
public void btnLoadGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmProgress progressForm = new frmProgress();

    try
    {
        progressForm.MdiParent = this;
        progressForm.Text = "Importing DSC_0";
        progressForm.Top = this.Height / 3 - progressForm.Height / 2;
        progressForm.Left = this.Width / 2 - progressForm.Width / 2;
        //ofd1.Title = "Import legacy DSC balances";
        //this.ofd1.ShowDialog(this);

        //Need code to empty grid before loading
        grd1.Rows.Clear();
        grd1.Refresh();

        //Load grid based on new selections
        GetUserSelections();
        GetUserRelatedInfo();
        LoadLabelForecastType();
        LoadGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        util.LogError(ex);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    progressForm.Close();         

}
```

And the progress bar itself:

```
namespace AmortClient
{
    public partial class frmProgress : Form
    {
        public frmProgress()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public ProgressBar Pbar
        {
            get { return this.pb1; }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The last time I used a progress bar I used a background worker and you just wrap all your "work" in a for loop. Here is the walk through I used. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Comment: A good tutorial.  very basic, but effective.  i think the original writer of my projects code might have used that, in conjunction with a few other things on generics and delegates, to come up with our system.  I only know so much about because I had to come in behind him and patch it later, which meant learning how the thing worked first!!! =D

Comment: Thanks, I'll be reading this and giving it a try over the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

We have a progress bar that uses Background thread and event callbacks.  It also uses the "params" parameter and delegates so that it can be generalized into any process in the code.

Here are a few little snippits...

```
private delegate T Method(ProgressBarCallBackInterface callingform, params object[] argsobject);

private void frmProgress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FormTitle))
    {
        lblSampleTitle.Text = FormTitle;
        this.Text = FormTitle;
    }
    else
    {
        lblSampleTitle.Text = string.Empty;
        this.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    bgWorkerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bgWorkerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Delegate method = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Method), instanceOfClassHavingTheFunction, FullFunctionName, true, true);
    if (method != null)
    {
        ReturnValue = ((Method)method)(this, Parameters);
    }
}

public void ReportProgress(int percentage, string statusText)
{
    lblProgress.SetPropertyThreadSafe(() => lblProgress.Text, statusText);
    bgWorkerThread.ReportProgress(percentage);
}
```

then in whatever code is using it, I can call

```
if (progressBar != null)
    progressBar .ReportProgress(6, "Verifying Journal Integrity");
```

my code is slightly more complicated because `T` cannot be `void`, so I had to add some switches and a secondary method to allow this to run on processes that have a `void` return.  But the basic shape is there.

Here is a sample of an entry point into the progress bar:

```
//note: FunctionName, Class Having Function, Params....
frmProgress _frmProgress = new frmProgress("UpdateRigX", RigFacade.Instance, rigX, dRigVersion, ModuleVersion);
_frmProgress.FormTitle = "Updating RigX...";
_frmProgress.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: this might be more complex than what you are looking to do...but it has the upside of being both generic and re-useable. :-)